# C# parse string to int32 - value too big

Tags: c#

I receive a string from an external interface which holds an `INT32` value. This value represents "-100" - a signed int - and thus, looking like this string "4294967196". 
If it would look like "-100" I could use `Int32.TryParse()` to cast it to a signed value. 
But in my case it interprets the values as is and tells me that the value is too big (>2.147.483.647).
Any workaround to get this working? How to tell the parser that the leading 1 is not a number?

**Edit:** Sorry for being inaccurate. The value I receive is a string that looks like this "4294967196". It represents an `Uint32` with the value -100. If the interface would return a string holding "-100" it would be possible to just use `Int32.TryParse()`. That's what I was trying to express.

Comment: What do you mean by "leading 1"?

Comment: What's wrong with `(int) (uint.Parse("4294967196"))`?

Comment: Am I missing something? You get a string that is `"-100"`, and it's equivalent to `"4294967196"`? I don't get what "If it would look like `-100` I could use `Int32.TryParse()` to cast it to a signed value" means since "-100" is "-100" to me. And "leading 1 is not a number?" - what does that mean?

Comment: @skiminok You should post that as an answer

Comment: I still couldn't get it how a string "-100" get converted to "4294967196" ??? I tried in VS int i=-100; then string s = i.ToString(); s is holding "-100", will really appreciate if somebody can explain

Comment: @Habib.OSU - post-edit, it makes more sense - he's getting the string "4294967196" from an external source, which represents an unsigned int of value -100.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `uint.TryParse()` and cast the result to `int`.

```
string s = "4294967196";
uint ux;
int x = 0;
if (uint.TryParse(s, out ux))
{
    x = (int)ux;
}
// x = -100
```

Comment: Ah, yes, @Habib fixed it first.

Comment: I don't seem to have the ability to add comments (too new?) but Habib's answer does have a slight problem that I can see. A UInt could parse correctly to a value an explicit Int32 cast would fail on. The line: `x = (int)ux;` would throw an exception if the value of the string exceeded 2,147,483,647. Not sure if that is a problem or not, but some small coding changes to handle that may be in order.

Comment: It is worth noting that this would not work in a checked context, because it would throw an OverflowException.