# trouble with using switch case

Tags: ios, objective-c, switch-statement

I have the following code snippet:

```
NSUInteger cmdWarning = [(NSNumber*)responseObject[kCmdResponseWarning] unsignedIntegerValue];
//this time cmdWarning has value 4294967196

   switch (cmdWarning) {
       //I defined #define kCmdWarningSSLException          -100                   
       case kCmdWarningSSLException:
             NSLog(@"error!");
                  break;
                  default: 
                  break;
                 }
```

> **Output:** error!
>
> **My expected result is:** Log "error!" isn't printed

Why does this happen ? How do I resolve this problem ? I appreciate your support. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the value of `cmdWarning`? What is the value of `kNetworkWarningSSLException`?

Comment: what is the value of kNetworkWarningSSLException?

Comment: I'm sorry for confusing , I edited my code

Comment: `cmdWarning` is being stored in an unsigned integer. Your case statement is using signed values. Use values that are both signed or both unsigned. That will help.

Comment: Thanks your comments , I think I have answer from this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10304969/c-sharp-parse-string-to-int32-value-too-big

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the `kCmdWarningSSLException` value which is integer : **-100**

when switch occurs, it tries to find the value : **4294967196** (which happened when integer -100 is stored in unsigned integer) the reason for the same is `NSUInteger` cannot store -ve values and it is unsigned integer.

To fix this change `NSUInteger cmdWarning` to `NSInteger cmdWarning =` and switch will find the proper case and will output "error!"